# Show: $n\mu(\left\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert\geq n\right\})\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let f be integrable. Show that
$$
n\mu(\left\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert\geq n\right\})\to 0\mbox{ for }n\to\infty.
$$
*Hint:* Use the dominated convergence theorem.

Hello, unfortunately I do not know how to use the dominated convergenct theorem here. Can you give me a hint how to start the proof?

Comment: Consider the characteristic functions of the sets mentioned in the limit.

Comment: Do you mean: $n\mu(\underbrace{\left\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert\geq n\right\}}_{=:A})=n\int_A1\, dx$?

Comment: Call it better $A_n$, but yes. Now, what could you use to dominate $n\cdot \chi_{A_n}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_n := \{x : |f(x)| \geq n\}$; we may write $\mu(A_n) = \int_X \chi_{A_n}(x)$ where $X$ is the entire measure space. Then $nA_n = \int_X n\chi_{A_n}(x)$. But now by definition of $A_n$ we have that

$$n\chi_{A_n}(x) \leq |f(x)|$$

for every $x \in X$. Indeed, fix an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and  an $x \in X$. If $x \notin A_n$ then $n\chi_{A_n}(x) = 0$ which is certainly less than or equal to $|f(x)|$. If $x \in A_n$, $n \chi_{A_n}(x) = n \leq |f(x)|$ by definition of $A_n$. Thus we may apply the DCT (since $f$ is integrable) to get that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\mu(A_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X n\chi_{A_n}(x)  = \int_X \lim_{n\to \infty} n\chi_{A_n}(x) =0.$$

> > **Exercise for OP:** Prove that for almost every $x$, the pointwise limit of $ n \chi_{A_n}(x)$ equals zero.  Hint: If $f$ is integrable, $f$ is finite valued for almost every $x$. So given such an $x$, there is some $n$ for which $|f(x)|  < n$ and so....

Comment: And so $\lvert f(x)\rvert < n$. That means that the measure of $\left\{x: \lvert f(x)\rvert\geq\infty\right\}$ only can have measure $0$, because all sets on which f takes the value $\infty$ are sets of measure $0$. Right?

Comment: @math12 Yes. But why does that mean the pointwise limit of $n \chi_{A_n}(x)$ equals zero?